# How to redirect to https except for pattern

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect to my https server config in nginx.conf except if the url has a pattern.

So basically I need to combine the redirect:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name foo.com;
    return 301 https://foo.com$request_uri;
}
```

And this server config blog:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name foo.com;

   location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      alias /etc/letsencrypt_webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
   }
}
```

Is there a way that if the current request isn't

```
http://foo.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/
```

Then it should perform the 301 redirect to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name foo.com;

   location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      alias /etc/letsencrypt_webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
   }
   location / {
      return 301 https://foo.com$request_uri;
   }

}
```

This is how we handle multiple services in a same domain. You might need to do some tweaking to make it work, but this is the skeleton

whenever a request  is comming to `http://foo.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/` then the 1st location block would work and for any other url  the below url would work

Comment: Is there a way to make the domain generic?  and to include www if it was there.